# CasperJs, how to repeat a step X times onWaitTimeout?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures, break, casperjs

So what I want to do is create a casperJS function which allows us to repeat a step X times, by refreshing the page first, when this step function reaches the timeout.

For unreliable test due to a specific page bug/freeze at the moment and reduce the percentage of false negative.

I have just a problem, I don't know how to break this loop, because I'm in IIFE scope, see following code :

```
var echoTest = function(){
    casper.echo('Hi');
};
var trueFunction = function(){
    return true;
};

var verifyFailedTest = function(number, trueReturn, thenFunction){
    var i = 0;
    //outer:       <-------
    for (; i <= number; i++){   // <------ how to break this loop in my function then()
        //IIFE
        (function(index){
            if (index < number-1){
                //Execute 'number-1' times the then() step (reload the page each time) if timeout or until trueReturn returns true
                casper.then(function(){
                    casper.waitFor(function checkReturnTrue(){
                            return trueReturn();
                        }
                        , function then() {
                            thenFunction();
                            //break outer; break; return false;    <------ here where I want to break the loop
                        }
                        , function timeout() { 
                            casper.reload();
                        });
                });
            }
            //last execution, will return the normal error if it fails each time
            else if (index === number){
                casper.then(function(){
                    casper.waitFor(function checkReturnTrue(){
                            return trueReturn();
                        }
                        , function then() {
                            console.log('else');
                            thenFunction();
                        });
                });
            }
            else{console.log('verifyFailedTest() bug');}
        })(i);
    }
};
```

I tried with label, but I got a syntax error.

Execution :

```
casper.test.begin('\n*************** Suite of planned test : scenario 1 **************\n', 1, function suite(test) {
    casper.start('https://www.google.fr/', function() {
        verifyFailedTest(3, trueFunction, echoTest);
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Any reason not to use promises? I see you're using `then` already, this looks like a simple promise retry pattern.

Comment: This then() comes from the [CasperJS API](http://casperjs.org/) which uses the promise pattern. As promised pattern is not mastered by everyone (not me either :p ), and CasperJS can be used without node, I would prefer to do it in native js.

Comment: You cannot break this, because the loop is long executed when the `then` blocks are beginning execution.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about it. So I can't do it with a loop. Do you have an idea how to do it? With `repeat()` or something. Because `onWaitTimeout` add a failure and I don't want one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think can do this without a for loop, by clustering your code into parts and do this recursively:

```
var verifyFailedTest = function(number, repeatStep, trueReturn){
    var index = 0;
    function intermediate(){
        casper.then(function(){
            repeatStep();
            casper.waitFor(function checkReturnTrue(){
                    return trueReturn();
                }
                , function then() {
                    this.test.pass("Test passes after " + (index+1) + " try");
                }
                , function timeout() { 
                    casper.reload();
                    if (index < number-1) {
                        intermediate();
                    } else {
                        lastTry();
                    }
                    index++;
                });
        });
    }
    function lastTry(){
        casper.then(function(){
            repeatStep();
            casper.waitFor(function checkReturnTrue(){
                    return trueReturn();
                }
                , function then() {
                    this.test.pass("Test passes after " + (index+1) + " try");
                });
        });
    }
    intermediate();
};
```

You'll have an error only after the number'th try.

But if you want to use your IIFE, the following might work by redefining `thenFunction` and skipping `then` block after you know that it is unnecessary (`doBreak === true`):

```
var verifyFailedTest = function(number, trueReturn, thenFunction){
    var i = 0, doBreak = false;
    var oldThenFunction = thenFunction;
    thenFunction = function(){
        doBreak = true;
        oldThenFunction();
    };
    for (; i <= number; i++){
        if (doBreak) {
            break;
        }
        // your IIFE here
        (function(index){
            if (index < number-1){
                //Execute 'number-1' times the then() step (reload the page each time) if timeout or until trueReturn returns true
                casper.then(function(){
                    if (doBreak) { return; }
                    casper.waitFor(...);
                });
            }
            //last execution, will return the normal error if it fails each time
            else if (index === number){
                casper.then(function(){
                    if (doBreak) { return; }
                    casper.waitFor(...);
                });
            }
            else{console.log('verifyFailedTest() bug');}
        })(i);
    }
};
```

Comment: Nop, doBreak remains false in the `verifyFailedTest()` scope.

Comment: @Fanch You can either nest the steps by giving up IIFE or use your IIFE but skip later steps when it succeeded. See my edit.

Comment: Ha yes, you're right, I could also use `skip()` method. Thx. Recursively is the cleanest way :p Don't need the timeout() method for the last try, casper defaut error is ok.

Comment: @Fanch Feel free to edit according to your needs and obviously when I made an error. :)

Comment: Thx, you can delete the thenFunction argument too. I just tried it with the `uploadFile` function (for an Image) in slimerJS -which seems a little buggy- and it works well. Ty again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use CasperJS's [`repeat(int times, Function then)`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#repeat) function.